# What is the 'fraction' value at the end of a Vector3.Lerp(); statement in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't quite understand what the 'fraction value means at the end of a lerp statement. I looked at the documentation and the unity scripting API, but my code just doesn't seem to be working. If you could help me figure out what the problem is here I would appreciate it!

Here is my code:

```
void Awake()
{
    StartCoroutine(waitWhileLerp());
}

private IEnumerator waitWhileLerp()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(lerpSpeed);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, PathfindingCalc(screenXRadius, screenYRadius, agenPathfinderRange), lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.Log(transform.position = (PathfindingCalc(screenXRadius, screenYRadius, agenPathfinderRange)));
    }
}

private Vector3 PathfindingCalc(float maxXAbsalute, float maxYAbsalute, float range)
{
    float x, y;
    x = Random.Range(transform.position.x - range, transform.position.x + range);
    y = Random.Range(transform.position.y - range, transform.position.y + range);

    x = Mathf.Clamp(x, -screenXRadius, screenXRadius);
    y = Mathf.Clamp(y, -screenYRadius, screenYRadius);
    return new Vector3(x, y, 0);
}
```

Comment: For now I just put the same speed I am using in the coroutine multiplied by Time.deltaTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lerp interpolates between two points, so it finds a point in between them and goes towards it. The third field is used to calculate that point: if the distance between your position and the target is 100 and you put fraction at .3 you will go from your position towards 30.
it should be between 0 and 1 (it is a fraction).
i don't think that converting with timedeltatime helps but i'm not sure about that.